# Add row to data.frame but only to certain columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I wish to create a data.frame and add rows but ONLY to certain columns. I want the remaining columns to be specified as NAs.

What I have is as follows:

```
#create empty data frame
x=data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=3))
> x
[1] X1 X2 X3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

#The data and its corresponding columns
> y=data.frame(col=c("X1","X3"),val=c(20,30))
> y
  col val
1  X1  20
2  X3  30
#select those columns (works fine)
> x[,y$col]
[1] X1 X2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#select and create a row for those columns and corresponding values
> x[,y$col]=y$val
Error in Summary.factor(1:2, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  min not meaningful for factors
```

So the question is how would you (efficiently) create the new rows. Im guessing there ought to be a way to do it without specifying the NAs yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems is that your `col` variable in `y` is a factor. This can easily be undone:

```
y=data.frame(col = c("X1","X3"), val = c(20,30), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Next, when you do

```
x[,y$col]=y$val
```

You don't specify a row number. Doing this would work though:

```
x[1,y$col] <- y$val

x

#   X1 X2 X3
# 1 20 NA 30
```

But then you'll soon run into problems if you have other X1's and X2's to write to the `x` dataframe. So your algorithm might need some brush-up, unless this is really what you need.

Comment: This is bit different to what I posted above but in my actual application I'm grabbing the val columns from another data.frame. i.e. not setting it myself so I don't get a chance to set stringsAsFactors=FALSE. I tried x[1,y$col] <- as.numeric(y$val) in my application but this didn't work either. Suggestions?

Comment: `x[1, as.character(y$col)]` should do it